# Force stl container size and declare it as a type

Tags: c++

I want to define a `std::vector` with 2 elements as a type, and export it.
Something looking like:

```
template <class T>
using Vec2 = std::vector<T>(2);
```

- Is it possible to force the size of a container ?
- If it is, how can I declare it as a type and export it in the whole code when I include its declaration file?

**Edit: A lot of interesting responses. Thanks to everyone, I will use a typedef struct because I don't really need to access container's member functions.**

Comment: Why do you want to use `std::vector`? Why not [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array)?

Comment: Use a `std::array` if you are going to know the size at compile time.

Comment: I though it was also possible with vectors etc

Comment: vectors of different size are of same type when they have the same type of elements (and same allocator). This smells like a [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Can you tell us why you think you need an alias for vectors of fixed type ? How would you use `Vec2` ?

Comment: @Auloma It doesn't.  The size of a vector is not part of its type because its size is a run-time attribute.  An arrays size is part of its type, so it can be used for something like this.

Comment: Yes I want to use it as a x, y functionnalities. Maybe I should use an interface instead

Comment: What about using `std::pair` instead ? If it is only to store x, y coordinates, `std::vector` is a bit overkill.

Comment: or why not simply `struct xy { int x; int y; }` ?

Comment: Yeah, probably a simpler solution. Don't know why I didn't think to it earlier

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. This is not possible because a `std::vector<int>` of size `2` has the same type as a `std::vector<int>` of size `42`. Vectors are resizable, thats basically what makes them vectors and distinguishes them from `std::array`. For a container of fixed size `2` you can use arrays:

```
template <class T>
using Vec2 = std::array<T,2>;
```